# Including a class using a relative path

Tags: php, include, relative-path

I'm trying to use a library in one of my classes, namely the PHPass library.

This is my basic directory structure:

```
/ (root)
    / mysite
        /application
            /models
                User_model.php
            /libraries
                PasswordHash.php
```

I want to include `PasswordHash.php` in `User_model.php`. I tried doing this:

```
// Load PHPass library
include_once('..\libraries\PasswordHash.php');
$hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
```

But PHP can't find the file:

```
Message: include_once(..\libraries\PasswordHash.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you try forward slash (/)?

Comment: Using ``\`` makes things complicated, since ``\`` is also the escape character in strings. The `/` does not have that problem, so that's save to use.

Comment: by the way you will run into problems if you want to include/use that model in a deeper structure like /mysite/web/deep/deeper/index.php ! you can override that problem by using absolute paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your current working directory, not the script it actually parses now. Try dumping

```
getcwd()
```

function output to figure out the current working dir. In order to use current file path, you can try

```
realpath(__FILE__)
```

and then construct relative path to it. Also, in order to not confuse slashes, you may use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant to separate folders, like:

```
require_once(realpath(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'classes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.php')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the / instead of the \.

Answer (score 1):

```
include_once('../libraries/PasswordHash.php');
```

try use "/" instead of "\".

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to solve this problem is to use the `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` PHP variable and concatenate then the absolute path. In your case:

```
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/mysite/application/libraries/PasswordHash.php";
```

It's not the best solution, because it can lead to a long statement. However, it's the only way I've found to make that kind of includes work.

*EXTRA TIP: the parenthesis of the include and require are redundant.*